# Ruby method as block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, event-handling

Currently there is a class in my Rails application which calls blocks as event handlers (callbacks):

```
class MyClass
  #Event handler hooks:

  def on_event1(&block)
    @on_event1 = block
  end

  def on_event2(&block)
    @on_event2 = block
  end

  #Event triggers:

  def do_event1
    @on_event1.call if @on_event1
  end

  def do_event2
    @on_event2.call if @on_event2
  end
end
```

Initializer:

```
mc = MyClass.new

#===== Event handlers: =====

mc.on_event1 do
  #do some stuff
end

mc.on_event2 do
  #do some stuff
end
```

I would like to put event handlers into separate class transforming them from blocks to methods:

```
class MyClassHandlers
   def self.event1_handler
     #do some stuff
   end

   def self.event2_handler
     #do some stuff
   end
end
```

How to call a method in a place where block should be given?

I would like to see event binding as something like:

```
mc = MyClass.new
mc.on_event1 = MyClassHandlers.event1_handler
mc.on_event2 = MyClassHandlers.event2_handler
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use lambdas:

```
mc = MyClass.new
mc.on_event1 = lambda { MyClassHandlers.event1_handler } 
mc.on_event2 = lambda { MyClassHandlers.event2_handler }
```

Comment: Thank you. The only problem left is to propagate all method's parameters from lambda to method one-by-one, if parameters are defined.